# Gmail wrapped random html element with tag <span class='im'></span>

Tags: html, reactjs, twig, gmail

There is a problem. I am sending an email using the html template and variable substitution inside. When I re-send an identical letter, Gmail randomly wraps some blocks in a span tag, which completely destroys my layout, how can I avoid this, given that my implementation inserts a whole block with divs into one , but this is not I think for writing normally. I read a little about this problem, but did not understand how to solve it.

Thanks for any questions!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be solved by the generation of a unique element in the subject of the letter, but I'm not sure